# Setting a Random Color

Tags: java, colors

I am having trouble setting up a random color using a class constant.

When I run the program, (this is just  small part of the code) it gives me

> method setColor in class Graphics cannot be applied to given types

I am very unfamiliar with how to set colors, can someone please explain?

```
 public static final int COLOR = (int) (Math.random() * 256);

    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                {
                    g.setColor(new Color(COLOR), (COLOR), (COLOR));
                    g.drawLine(r.nextInt(MIDX), r.nextInt(MIDY), r.nextInt(MIDX), r.nextInt(MIDY));
                }
```

Comment: You are missing 1 opening brace in this line `g.setColor(new Color(COLOR), (COLOR), (COLOR));`. It should be `g.setColor(new Color((COLOR), (COLOR), (COLOR));` or more better `g.setColor(new Color(COLOR, COLOR, COLOR));`

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
g.setColor(new Color(COLOR, COLOR, COLOR));
```

Basically this is the constructor of Color `Color(int r, int g, int b)`  that you are trying to call.
r,g,b can have values in the range from 0 to 255. In your case it seems that r,g,b will have same value as you are using same constant.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your Color is not random because R , G and B are all equal so it will be grayish

```
g.setColor(new Color(RCOMPONENT, GCOMPONENT , BCOMPONENT));
```

Generate three random ints and do like above

Answer (score 0):

You have to get three random values between `0 to 255` and then construct the `Color` object.

```
int red=20;
int green=33;
int blue=33;
Color color=new Color(red,green,blue);
g.setColor(color);
```